# Denote by $T$ the linear transformation induced by $$. Find $T^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Consider the matrices:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1&2\\
    -2&3
    \end{bmatrix}\text{  and  }B=\begin{bmatrix}
                                    0&1\\
                                    2&0
                                \end{bmatrix}$

Denote by $T$ the linear transformation induced by $$. Find $T^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
1\\1
\end{bmatrix}$

We have $AB=\begin{bmatrix}
4&1\\
6&-2
\end{bmatrix}$. From that I can find $T\begin{bmatrix}
1\\1
\end{bmatrix}$ by find $AB_T$, but what should I do to find $T^{-1}$?I need find $AB_{T^{-1}}$? I don't have any idea. Help me!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What have you tried regarding the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AB$ can be considered as the matrix of the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2,(x,y)\mapsto\color{Red} {(u,v )}=(4x+y,6x-2y)$. So you have the system $\begin{cases} \color{Red} u=4x+y\\ \color{Red} v=6x-2y \end{cases}$, which is equivalent to $\begin{cases} x=\frac{1}{14}(2\color{Red} u+\color{Red}  v) \\ y=\frac{1}{14}(6\color{Red} u-4\color{Red} v) \end{cases}$. So, for $\color{Red} {(u,v)=(1,1)}$, $T^{-1}(\color{Red} {(1,1)})=\frac{1}{14}(3,2)$. You can check: $\frac{1}{14}\begin{bmatrix}4 & 1 \\6 & -2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3 \\2
\end{bmatrix}=\color{Red} {\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1\end{bmatrix}}$.

Comment: I appreciate your help. But to find $T^{-1}$ do we have to find the system of equations $(AB)^{-1}$?. So $\begin{cases} \color{Red} u=-2x-y\\ \color{Red} v=-6x+4y \end{cases}$. And $T^{-1}((1,1))=\frac{1}{14}(3, 1)$. Is my thinking correct? Or not?

Comment: This is my solution for that https://i.stack.imgur.com/brGtV.png

Comment: It all amounts to the same thing. But above all, there are several careless errors in what you have written which you should correct. :)

Comment: What is this? can you be more detailed?

Comment: $\begin{cases}  x=-\frac{1}{14}(-2u-v)\\  y=-\frac{1}{14}(-6u+4v) \end{cases}$. Isn't-it ?

Comment: Yes. But why you say all it same?

Comment: I think if you say $T^{-1}((1,1))=\frac{1}{14}(3, 2)$ it was same with $T((1,1))$ because $T((1,1))=\frac{1}{14}(3, 2)$

Comment: Matrix calculus is just one computational aspect of linear algebra; what is important here is that we have a linear transformation. No matter how we translate it (system, formula with matrices,...), we only translate linearity. $T(\frac{1}{14}(3,2))=(1,1)$

Comment: It's silly. I had an error in the calculation. You're right. I was clear it. Thanks for the help.